# Ignore .git in parent directories for git status, branch, etc?

Tags: git

Is it possible to prevent git from searching parent directories for `.git` folders?  I have a `.git` in my user root directory to back up / branch my config files, but that has the undesired consequence that all subdirectories that don't have their own `.git` folders appear to be children of the user root.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting this in your .bashrc:

```bash
export GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES='/home/keflavich'
```

If you're in a subdirectory of /home/keflavich, the .git stuff in /home/keflavich will be invisible. But if you're in /home/keflavich, it will be visible, which I think is what you want.

Comment: I feel like the other answers did not quite understand the original question. This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: This has the potential to be very useful for the way I sometimes have git repos nested within git repos that neither of the repos need be aware of. (so git submodules and git subtree just add complexity) ... however ... I also found that when I corrected my script to not move the .git folder in the nested repo to a subfolder, that I didn't need the export statement. So make sure that your .git folder is where you expect it to be ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.gitignore` that ignores *everything* (i.e. its contents is just `*`). That way, nothing will be tracked or recognized by Git *unless* you explicitely tell Git to do it, i.e. add a file to the repository using `git add -f filename`.

Comment: Technically, you'd need to `git add -f <filename>`, since otherwise Git will complain about adding files that are ignored.

Comment: OK, that works for ignoring files, but if I run `git status` it still tells me I'm "in" the parent git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.gitignore` to ignore all subfolders by using the line

> `/*/`

(that is, forward slash, asterisk, forward slash) the first slash means it refers to the root of the repo, the asterisk means "any name", the trailing slash means "only directories".

Any directories that you do want to track, you can add with `git add -f`.

See also the man pages of [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [`git add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).